# Trying to make MS Graph mocking work after updating to v5

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to update a project to Graph v5, however, after the update I cannot get the mocking to work

```
    private readonly Mock<GraphServiceClient> _mockGraphClient = new(
    MockBehavior.Strict,
    new Mock<IAuthenticationProvider>(MockBehavior.Strict).Object
```

);

Here's my exception: Can not instantiate proxy of a class Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient

I know the mocking method has changed but I cannot find any info on how this should be changed or what methods to use. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the constructor, you are trying to call, has two parameters

```
public GraphServiceClient(IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, string baseUrl = null)
```

You need to explicitly set also the second parameter `baseUrl`

```
private readonly Mock<GraphServiceClient> _mockGraphClient = new(MockBehavior.Strict, new MockAuthenticationProvider().Object, null);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work

Comment: @bkoz Does it throw the same exception? Could you share the whole test?